# how to addition int and decimal c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to addition decimal number and int number to find total number. Item.TotalPrice is decimal.

```
@foreach (OrderItem Item in Order.OrderItem.ToList())
        {

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td> </td>
                    <td>@Item.TotalPrice </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            int TotalPrice = Convert.ToInt32(Item.TotalPrice);
            int Total = Total + TotalPrice;
        }
```

Comment: What's the problem clearly? Where Total is used on your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're re-declaring your total variable every time. I think you want to do this:

```
@{
int Total = 0;
}
@foreach (OrderItem Item in Order.OrderItem.ToList())

    {

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td> </td>
                <td>@Item.TotalPrice </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        int TotalPrice = Convert.ToInt32(Item.TotalPrice);
        Total = Total + TotalPrice;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code definitely does something wrong. Please, describe what you were going to do.
Let me **guess**, you have an array of `OrderItem` objects having `TotalPrice` value and you want to output their `TotalPrice`s and it's sum.

```
@{
    int total = 0;
}
<table>
    @foreach (OrderItem item in Order.OrderItem.ToList())
    { 
        <tr>
            <td>@item.SomeValue1</td>     
            <td>@item.SomeValue2</td>     
            <td>@item.SomeValue3</td>     
            <td>@item.TotalPrice</td>     
        </tr>
        total += item.TotalPrice;
    }
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total: @total</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

That's how the problem described above can be solved.
If you were supposed to do something else, please, comment.

By the way, about your `Order.OrderItem.ToList()`. It is incorrect.
*First*, you have a `List` which means that it is `Order.OrderItems` at least.
*Second*, your `Order.OrderItem` variable is the same as it's type `OrderItem` (i.e. it is `public OrderItem[] OrderItem`) which is incorrect. Give it another name like `Items`.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the `Total` variable in each iteration.

You'll need something, such as this

```
@{
    int Total = 0;
    foreach (OrderItem Item in Order.OrderItem.ToList())
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Item.TotalPrice </td>
        </tr>
        Total += Convert.ToInt32(Item.TotalPrice);
    }
}
```